# How do I decode the response from an AVAX RPC Call in Vanilla Javascript?

Tags: javascript, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, avalanche

I am trying to fetch the latest block from the Avalanche network's public RPC server. I have succeeded in sending JSON-RPC calls to their server and I get a response. The problem is how to decode the response and make meaning out of the data returned.

Here are my attempts

```html
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script>

      jQuery.ajax({
    url: "https://api.avax.network/ext/bc/C/rpc",
    type: "post",
    data: JSON.stringify({
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 65,
    "method": "eth_getBlockByNumber",
    "params": ["latest", false]
  }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType   : "json",
    success    : function (data) {
      console.log((data.result.gasUsed))
            console.log(data);
        },
    error      : function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
        console.log(xhr);
    }
});
</script>
```

My issue now is that each time I try to decode each value from the response object, it fails. I've tried using hexcode to string converter, but it doesn't work. Here is the code snippet I've tried:

```
function hex2a(hex) {
var str = '';
for (var i = 0; i < hex.length; i += 2) {
    var v = parseInt(hex.substr(i, 2), 16);
    if (v) str += String.fromCharCode(v);
}
return str;
```

}

This does not return a readable string. And I am stuck on a side project. Can someone help me out?

Comment: The returned block data is already decoded. What kind of "readable string" exactly are you looking for?

Comment: I want to read the value for each hexcode. Example "0x1c6500"

Answer (score 2):

You can use the native `parseInt()` function to convert hex numbers to their decimal form.

Example: `parseInt(0x1c6500)` returns `1860864`.

Comment: Wow! You just saved my entire life..... Thank you so much for this. I have spent the last two days on this very issue. 

This is a very beautiful new year gift.